# Jira Rest API - How to login

Tags: ruby, rest, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I've been going through this guide: [JIRA API Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication#JIRARESTAPIExample-BasicAuthentication-Simpleexample) and can't seem to figure out how to simply authenticate to the API if you're using gmail to login to Jira. I'm hoping to use the REST API within my ruby app in order to link github and jira

Edit: Code:

```
    uri = URI.parse("https://<address>.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/<issue-name>")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    request["user"] = "<username>"
    request["password"] = "<password>"
    @jira_response = http.request(request)
```

With the above code; I get a HTTP unauthorized response.

Comment: Show us some code. We can't help fix what you've written without that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved by using;

```
request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

instead of:

```
request["user"] = "<username>"
request["password"] = "<password>"
```

Comment: Award yourself the answer once SO lets you. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I wrote a small skeleton app for using the Jira api. It may or may not be helpful for you. See https://github.com/vaneyckt/SimpleJira.